# Buffer for this type not yet supported when using rpy2 in jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science, data-visualization, rpy2

I have installed all the packages required for rpy2, I want to embed R code in the jupyter notebook to do the data visualization.

But there's not much luck so far in my case, please point out which part I did wrong. Hope for a solution.

```
# Import the libraries

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rpy2

# Imports required from rpy2
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri   
pandas2ri.activate()
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

```
SheetA = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\test\\SheetA.csv')
SheetA_header=['Grill Type', 'Pre-Heat Time (In Seconds)', 'Fuel Cost Per Meal ($)', 'Market Share (%)', 'Ease Of Use', 'Life Span (In Years)', 'Initial Investment ($)']
SheetA=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\test\\SheetA.csv", header=None, skiprows=1, names=SheetA_header)
SheetA = pd.DataFrame(SheetA)
```

```
%%R -i SheetA

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(SheetA)

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\ipython\rmagic.py in _(obj)
    147     if 'data.frame' in obj.rclass:
    148         # request to turn it to a pandas DataFrame
--> 149         res = converter.ri2py(obj)
    150     else:
    151         res = ro.sexpvector_to_ro(obj)

D:\Anaconda\lib\functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    838                             '1 positional argument')
    839 
--> 840         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    841 
    842     funcname = getattr(func, '__name__', 'singledispatch function')

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in ri2py_listvector(obj)
    181 def ri2py_listvector(obj):
    182     if 'data.frame' in obj.rclass:
--> 183         res = ri2py(DataFrame(obj))
    184     else:
    185         res = numpy2ri.ri2py(obj)

D:\Anaconda\lib\functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    838                             '1 positional argument')
    839 
--> 840         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    841 
    842     funcname = getattr(func, '__name__', 'singledispatch function')

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in ri2py_dataframe(obj)
    188 @ri2py.register(DataFrame)
    189 def ri2py_dataframe(obj):
--> 190     items = tuple((k, ri2py(v)) for k, v in obj.items())
    191     res = PandasDataFrame.from_items(items)
    192     return res

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    188 @ri2py.register(DataFrame)
    189 def ri2py_dataframe(obj):
--> 190     items = tuple((k, ri2py(v)) for k, v in obj.items())
    191     res = PandasDataFrame.from_items(items)
    192     return res

D:\Anaconda\lib\functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    838                             '1 positional argument')
    839 
--> 840         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    841 
    842     funcname = getattr(func, '__name__', 'singledispatch function')

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in ri2py_vector(obj)
    137 @ri2py.register(SexpVector)
    138 def ri2py_vector(obj):
--> 139     res = numpy2ri.ri2py(obj)
    140     return res
    141 

D:\Anaconda\lib\functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    838                             '1 positional argument')
    839 
--> 840         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    841 
    842     funcname = getattr(func, '__name__', 'singledispatch function')

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\numpy2ri.py in ri2py_sexp(obj)
    157 def ri2py_sexp(obj):
    158     if (obj.typeof in _vectortypes) and (obj.typeof != VECSXP):
--> 159         res = numpy.asarray(obj)
    160     else:
    161         res = ro.default_converter.ri2py(obj)

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: Buffer for this type not yet supported.
```

There's must be something wrong when processing dataframe to rpy2, only a guess.

Comment: Anyone?........